# How to add rows and columns dynamically based on input from another page

Tags: html, angularjs

From one html page I am sending the number of rows and columns I need on next html.
Controller code for same is:

```
.controller('decisionController', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$state',  function($scope,$rootScope,  $state){
    $rootScope.decvalues;
    $scope.saveDecision = function(isValid){
        var values=[];
        var nameAndDec={
                name:$scope.model.name,
                description:$scope.model.description,
                input_col:$scope.no_of_input,//number of columns
                output_col:$scope.no_of_output,//number of columns
                rows:$scope.no_of_row,//number of rows

        };
        values.push(nameAndDec);
        $rootScope.decvalues=values[0];
        $state.go('rulesEditor.decisionTble');
    },
```

On my second html page I want to create a dynamic table based on the number of rows and columns passed from first page.
 I want to show this kind of structure on second html page with given number of rows and columns

[image]

This is my second html page:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <!--For getting a checkbox in eack row -->
        <th ng-repeat="values in decvalues.rows">

          </th>
<!--Add number of input columns header as per input got from first page -->
          <th ng-repeat="values in decvalues.input_col">
           (I) &lt;enter data&gt;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"></input>
          </th>
<!--Add number of output columns header as per input got from first page -->
          <th ng-repeat="values in decvalues.output_col" >
           (O) &lt;enter data&gt;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"></input>
          </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<!--Add number of rows as per input got from first page -->
    <tr ng-repeat="row in decvalues.rows">
       <td ng-repeat="col in decvalues.input_cols">
     (I) &lt;enter data&gt;
   </td>
   <td ng-repeat="col in decvalues.output_cols">
     (O) &lt;enter data&gt;
   </td>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am getting this values on my controller, but on my second page table is not generating

[image]
I tried many things but it is not working, can anyone please suggest how to implement this using angular. 
It would be a great help

Comment: I'm not sure where you got stuck: passing the model from one controller to the next or drawing the table?

Comment: I am stuck in drawing the table with dynamic rows and columns

Comment: Just saw your second edit. At this point I think it would be helpful to understand how your model is constructed. Please see my answer and see if you can do something similar to that (disregard thead, you seem to have that covered)

Comment: Your directive is `ng-repeat="values in decvalues.rows"`. However, from page 1, `devalues.rows` is an integer, not an array. The same problem exists for the column directives. In order to generate a table from the data, the data should be a table (an array of arrays).

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be an array of arrays, but ng-repeat iterates over arrays, so that's needed. Please see my edit

Comment: maybe add the $rootScope.decvalues to the scope of your second controller such as : $scope.decvalues = $rootScope.decvalues; ? Plus ng-repeat iterates over an array not an integer so your rows and col must be of the proper length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` to the rescue!

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="header in model.headers">{{header.title}}</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in decvalues.rows track by $index">
       <td ng-repeat="col in decvalues.input_cols track by $index">
         // stuff
       </td>
       <td ng-repeat="col in decvalues.output_cols track by $index">
         //stuff
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As Austin pointed out, you also need to change your model to this:

```
var nameAndDec={
                name:$scope.model.name,
                description:$scope.model.description,
                input_col:new Array($scope.no_of_input),//number of columns
                output_col:new Array($scope.no_of_output),//number of columns
                rows:new Array($scope.no_of_row),//number of rows

        };
```

In order to iterate

Comment: I tried this in [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UwCyueLhb6bbdIuei0D7?p=preview) and ran into the problem that `ng-repeat` doesn't like repeated instances of `undefined` in the data source array. You might need a loop that creates empty objects. Better yet, the loop could instantiate meaningful data objects.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that, too bad. I agree with your comment. Since you're already looping you might as well make an array of numbers. I just wish there was a way to do list comprehension as in Haskell \ Python :\ I'll wait for OP feedback before editing

Comment: @Austin Mullins it's the good solution juste add track by $index at the end of the ng-repeat :  ng-repeat="col in decvalues.output_cols track by $index"

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Your question is poorly explained, if the problem is that you do not succed in creating a dynamic table, please show us what you tried to do.
Otherwise I would sugest you create a table template with 2 ng-repeat

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows">
        <td ng-repeat="columns"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am able to fetch the data on second page, but the problem I am currently facing is I am not able to generate the dynamic table with the dynamic number of rows and columns passed.

Comment: Then show the code of your second page not the first. If the data is not the problem don't show how you send it.

Comment: Added the code for second page, please correct me with what I have done wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it worked. the thing i was doing wrong was I was not iterating controller's array, and then the solution provided worked.. Thank you :)